# Is there a simple null safe operator for Kotlin function references?

Tags: kotlin

I'd like to pass a function reference on a nullable object. To take an Android example, say I want to use `Activity#onBackPressed` from a fragment that is a child of that actvity.

If I wanted to invoke this function, I could easily do

```
activity?.onBackPressed()
```

However, say I wanted to pass that as a reference instead:

```
val onBackPressedRef = activity::onBackPressed
```

This gives the familiar null safe error of **Only safe or non null assserted calls are allowed...**

---

I can get the error to go away with the following, but using `!!` is obviously not ideal:

```
val onBackPressedRef = activity!!::onBackPressed
```

Attemping `activity?::onBackPressed` was my first instinct, but this also breaks with several errors, where the interpreter seems confused.

```
val onBackPressedRef = activity?.let { it::onBackPressed }
```

This last variation *works*, but it's a lot more ugly than just using `?::`. I checked all the docs I could find, but I feel like I'm missing something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right, there is no `?::` operator in Kotlin.
You have several alternatives:

### 1. `let` and `run`

Thus, you have to use a helper function. Instead of `let()`, you can also use `run()`, making the expression a tiny bit shorter:

```
val onBackPressedRef = activity?.let { it::onBackPressed }
val onBackPressedRef = activity?.run { ::onBackPressed }
```

But keep in mind that either way, the invocation will be more verbose, too:

```
onBackPressedRef?.invoke(args)
```

Thus you should ask yourself, if this is really what you want, or if a no-op function call is also acceptable.

### 2. Closures

You could use a closure -- this will change semantics however:

```
val onBackPressedRef = { activity?.onBackPressed() }
```

Here, `onBackPressedRef` is not nullable anymore, so you can call it using the `()` operator, and in case of null `activity` it will have no effect.

### 3. Helper function

If function references with nullable objects are something you encounter a lot, you can write your own little abstraction:

```
// Return type: () -> Unit
fun <T> funcRef(obj: T?, function: T.() -> Unit) = { obj?.function() }
```

This trades a different syntax for a non-null function variable:

```
 // activity can be null
 val onBackPressedRef = funcRef(activity, Activity::onBackPressed)

 // Callable directly
 onBackPressedRef()
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Per your suggestion, a simple closure ended up being the simplest and most elegant solution for what I wanted to accomplish.